# Считывание из XML файла

Tags: c#

Есть `XML` файл, он лежит в сторонней от программы папке. Как из него считать информацию?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте класс `XDocument`:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("path\To\XmlFile");
```

Например, есть `xml` такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <status type="OK">200</status>
  <Text>Ok</Text>
</Response>
```

Тогда получить значение элемента (тега) можно так:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("path\To\XmlFile");
string status = xdoc.Root.Element("status").Value;
```

Атрибут:

```
string type = xdoc.Root.Element("status").Attribute("type").Value;
```

Comment: и как обратиться к конкретному полю?

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если ответ Вас устраивает, отмечайте его как правильный (галка слева от ответа).